# Define an explicit function $f$ such that the $n$th derivative is continuous but the $n+1$st derivative of $F$ is undefined at 0.

Tags: calculus

What I have tried so far is to construct a function such that the $n$th derivative is some constant $a$ times $\sqrt{x}$, since the next derivative would give $\frac{1}{2} a x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ which is undefined at 0. My problem comes from the wording of the problem which says the function should be $\textit{explicit}$ as I am unable to find a satisfying expression for $a$ in terms of $n$. I have noticed that each antiderivative of $\sqrt{x}$ increases by 1, so the exponent of the function in question could be written something similar to, $ax^{\frac{2n+1}{2}}$. Perhaps there is a better function which would not require fidgeting with constants.

Comment: Hello :) What do you think about $x\mapsto x^{n}|x|$?

Comment: This seems to work. I would not have thought of this! What about the problem suggested to you that this would be a solution? Also, I thought one couldn't differentiate $|x|$, but wolfram alpha seems to come up with a solution. How exactly do you find a derivative of your function when product rule would require a derivative of $|x|$?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with $n = 0$. The $0$th derivative of $f_0$ is just $f_0$ itself. So we need a continuous function which is not differentiable at $0$. We can take $f_0(x) = |x|$ as a simple example.

Now suppose we have come up with $f_n$ which is $n$-times continuously differentiable but whose $n+1$th derivative at 0 does not exist. Then we can define $f_{n + 1}(x) = \int\limits_{0}^x f_n(t) dt$. Clearly, $f_{n + 1}$ is $n + 1$-times differentiable. But its $n + 2$th derivative doesn't exist at 0.

It turns out that the explicit formula for $f_n(x)$ defined in this way is $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n |x|}{(n + 1)!}$. This is fairly easy to check - we see that $\frac{d}{dx} f_{n + 1}(x) = f_n(x)$, and that $f_{n + 1}(0) = 0$, so it is indeed true that $f_{n + 1}(x) = \int\limits_0^x f_n(t) dt$.